# aSyncTask running only once

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an Android Bluetooth App and I use aSyncTask when I want to scan available device around mine. This `aSyncTask` is simple, in `"onPreExecute()"`, I use `"myBluteoothAdaptaer.startDiscovery()"` to discover devices and `"myBluteoothAdaptaer.cancelDiscovery()"` in `"onPostExecute()"` to stop it.

But when I run my app, the `doInBackground()` function is executed only one time on the 1st click. If I click again on the button, Button's code work but aSyncTask isn't executed properly (when it work, a progressBar need 2s to be complete. When it doesn't work, it only need around `0.1 ms` to complete it).

So maybe this error is coming from `doInBackground()`, stop at `onPreExecute()` or something like this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code :

Button click code : (just set a )

```
/** Scan on click **/
    Scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // click on SCAN button
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!blueAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                //blueAdapter.startDiscovery();
                Scan_btn_clic = true;
            } else {
                //blueAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                Scan_btn_clic = false;
            }
            Maj scan = new Maj();
            scan.execute();
        }
    });
    /***********/
```

doInBackground() function :

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        int progress;
        for (progress=0;progress<=100;progress++)
        {
            if (blueAdapter.isEnabled() && Scan_btn_clic == false || !blueAdapter.isEnabled())
            {
                for (int i=0; i<5000000; i++){}
                //la méthode publishProgress met à jour l'interface en invoquant la méthode onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(progress);
                progress++;
            }
            else if (blueAdapter.isEnabled() && Scan_btn_clic == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
                //la méthode publishProgress met à jour l'interface en invoquant la méthode onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(progress);
                progress++;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try `Thread.sleep(sec);` inside task

Comment: Did you notice that the for loop in `Scan_btn_clic == false` is 20 times shorter than the other one? That might explain the difference in time as that is also 20 times shorter. More important though; If you want to wait a certain amount of time, use `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` rather than a for loop. The difference is that the the for loop is less accurate and it actually uses CPU cycles

Comment: I got 2 `for()` to wait 2 different times according to which button is clicked. I tried to use `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` instead of `for()` loop and it's worked ! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple, thanks to Jyoti JK and 0xDEADC0DE for help.

Only need to use `Thread.sleep(milli)` instead of `for()` loop.

Now my aSyncTask is working well